# Error in Insert Statement with Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error when I am executing the following statement

```
INSERT INTO upcoming_matches(
    Id, Date, me_date, Match, team1, team2, 
    Timing, Status, series_id, 
    match_place,series_mtch_type, match_live,match_result, MINI_LINK, 
    PHOTOS_URL, scorecard_ID) 
VALUES(
    764, '2012/03/11', '2012/03/11', 'Bangla vs Pak', '2', '6', 
    '08:00 GMT | 14:00 local 13:30 IST', 1, 171, 
    'Shere Bangla National Stadium, Mirpur', 'ODI', 1, '', '1483',  
    'http://www.cricandcric.com/photo-gallery/', 3258)
GO

[Error] Script lines: 1-5 --------------------------
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Match, team1, team2, Timing, Status, series_id, match_place,
 series_mtch_type, ' at line 1 

 Warnings: ---> 
   W (1): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Match, team1, team2, Timing, Status, series_id, match_place,
 series_mtch_type, ' at line 1
          <---
```

Can any one please help me with this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` is a [reserved mysql keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you need to enclose it with backticks

```
`match`
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to close the statement with the `GO` keyword in MySQL, you have to close it with the semicolon `;`

You have also to put backtick around any field name that could contain reserved keywork or capitalized field.